# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'text'

Tags: python, html

```
{{% extends "base.html %}

{% block content %}
<h1 style="text-align: center">Owner Index</h1>


<fieldset align="centre">
    <body>
    {% for value in p %}
    {{ value.id }}<br>
    {{ value.start_location }}<br>
    {{ value.start_time }}<br>
    {{ value.drop_location }}<br>
    {{ value.car_model }}<br>
    {{ value.car_number}}<br>
    {% endfor %}
    </body>
</fieldset>
{% endblock %}
```

I am trying to print the values sent in p from python but always getting this error.

Comment: Is the extra curly bracket in the first line actually in your code?
That could be causing a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
{{ extends "base.html %}
```

with this line

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```